# ifelse statement with mutate in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I've written the following code in R which works fine. However, assuming I had to apply a similar code to a factor variable with several levels (> 6), `ifelse` statements can be quite difficult to read. I'm wondering if there are any other more efficient ways of writing an easy to read code but still using dplyr.

```
  library(dplyr)
  mtcars %>% arrange(gear) %>%
  mutate(gearW = ifelse(gear == 3, "Three", ifelse(gear == 4, "Four", "Five")))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use  `factor`

```
mtcars %>% 
  arrange(gear) %>% 
  mutate(gearW = as.character(factor(gear, levels=3:5, 
        labels= c("three", "four", "five"))))
```

Or another option is `english`

```
library(english)
mtcars %>%
        arrange(gear) %>%
        mutate(gearW = as.character(english(gear)))
```

EDIT: Added the `as.character` from @David Arenburg's and @Konrad Rudolph's comments.

Comment: Great! Thanks for that quick answer!

Comment: Beware that this gives you `factor` as a result type, not `character`. That’s fine, but sometimes unexpected. Coerce it to `character` if necessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Thanks for that useful insight! I shall bear that in mind.

Comment: (This question has become incredibly common recently, maybe we should create an [tag:r-faq] for this? There [doesn’t seem to be one yet](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br-faq%5D+ifelse+factor)).

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for that.  The class `english` needs to be converted to `character` within the `%>%`